# The difference between "need + infinitive" and "need + gerund"

Tags: grammar, gerunds, infinitives

What is the difference between

"I don't need to learn."

And

"I don't need learning."?

It is said that "need + gerund" is passive, meaning what "I don't need learning" actually means is "I don't need to be learned." I just want to confirm whether this is true or not in this case. I know it is true in case of some (or maybe all?) sentences such as "this house needs fixing."

Comment: We say "to learn" but not the passive *"to be learned". Instead we say "to be taught (something) (by someone)" or "to be schooled/educated." You can say "I don't need teaching/schooling."

Comment: Yeah but what if it is used metaphorically or in a literary way? Like someone telling their date "I need some time to learn you"?

Comment: It's OK only as humor or a parody, as in "I don't need no learning--what I needs is feeding," but not if your are serious. You would say "I need time to learn (more) about you" or "I need more time to understand you better." You can learn (transitive) something but not someone.

Comment: Thanks. So in conclusion, "I don't need learning" is wrong? I mean in a normal and serious context where there is no parody intended

Comment: 1) Is that really a gerund, e.g. in "this house needs fixing"? 2) If not, then it sure is in "a little learning is a dangerous thing." The "learning" example only works because there's an established (non-transitive) meaning for "learning." I'd argue your formula only works for transitive verbs.

Comment: Can you point to the source that gives this formula, that "need plus [what I'm going to call an -ing infinitive] always equals 'needs this verb performed upon it'"?

Comment: @AndyBonner https://www.grammaring.com/to-infinitive-or-gerund-need-require-want

Comment: 'I don't need learning' uses deverbal 'learning'. From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/learning): << _learning_: knowledge or a piece of information obtained by study or experience:
_His friends praised his generosity, wit, and learning._ >> But 'I don't need learning' is an unusual-sounding statement. // 'I don't need to be learned' uses the pure adjective, the bisyllable.

Comment: If you use it like this: *Like someone telling their date* "I need some time to learn you"... Then yes, the date replies: "I don't need to be learned." Which could also be expressed as: "I don't need learning." It's odd but correct.